# Android: Overlap in ExpandableListview in LinearLeyout

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

In my android application i have an expandable list view and a button in a linearLayout but when i open a sublist, some kind of overlap between items and just listview is in layout and button hidde under listview. I have 2 item over each other. one of them is hiding under other.
How can i fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/expandableListView"/>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/backup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BackUp"
                android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. Can you take a screenshot and post it somewhere and provide a link to it so we can see what you mean.

Comment: image of code:
http://i44.tinypic.com/28tbyn8.png
http://i41.tinypic.com/977g45.png

Comment: It solved.
    <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/backup"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BackUp"
            android:clickable="true" />